# usb4java. Не работает повторной поиск устройства

Tags: java, libusb

Здравствуйте. Использую библиотеку usb4java (обёртка над libusb). Выполняю поиск устройства и отправку сообщения. После, отсоединяю устройство, срабатывает событие, что устройство отсоединили и начинаю повторно искать устройство. Подсоединяем устройство и методы библиотеки не видят устройство, как подключенное.

Получение концентратора компьютера findDeviceConcrete

```
public Boolean findDeviceConcrete() {
    try {
        UsbServices usbServices = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        UsbHub hub = usbServices.getRootUsbHub();
        device = findDevice(hub);
        if (device == null) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (UsbException | SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(USBTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Поиск нужного устройства findDevice

```
    private UsbDevice findDevice(UsbHub hub) {
    UsbDevice usbDevice;

    for (UsbDevice devices : (List<UsbDevice>) hub.getAttachedUsbDevices()) {
        if (devices.isUsbHub()) {
            usbDevice = findDevice((UsbHub) devices);
            if (usbDevice != null) {
                return usbDevice;
            }
        } else {
            UsbDeviceDescriptor desc = devices.getUsbDeviceDescriptor();
            if (desc.idVendor() == VENDOR_ID
                    && desc.idProduct() == PRODUCT_ID) {
                return devices;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Данные методы не находят устройство после его отключение-подключения.

Так же после нахождения устройства происходит "рукопожатие" (claim)

```
        UsbConfiguration configuration = device.getUsbConfiguration((byte) 1);
        UsbInterface iface = configuration.getUsbInterface((byte) 0);
        iface.claim(new UsbInterfacePolicy() {
            @Override
            public boolean forceClaim(UsbInterface usbInterface) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал под low-level usb4java ([Документация](http://usb4java.org/quickstart/libusb.html)) и заработало, только под Windows очень не стабильно. Так же на GitHub проекта есть [примеры](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-examples/) использования.